# understanding php handling of static methods (non-static method cannot be called statically)

Tags: php, static-methods

```
<?php

class T {
        public function x(){
                return true;
        }    
}
var_dump(T::x());

class X {
        public function x(){
                return true;
        }

}    
var_dump(X::x());
```

This code results in:

```
bool(true)
PHP Fatal error:  Non-static method X::x() cannot be called statically in test.php on line 16
```

Why does T::x() works (when it should fail) and X::x() fails (as it should)?

Comment: well, self, parent and static are also doing non-static calls. Are you sure that `$x = T::x();` is successful?!

Comment: Notice that in testY(), you are making a T object but not an X object. That seems to be making a difference.

Comment: @bwoebi that's exactly what i find strange in all this. I copy pasted the core i'm running. feel free to reproduce and see if it works any different. also, will update with my php/phpunit versions, that may be useful.

Comment: @gcb please modify your question a bit as it actually is totally unrelated to phpunit… (and it should be searchable by google with more obvious search queries…) http://3v4l.org/l5v8p is much more comprehensive as a question…

Comment: @bwoebi done. question is much clearer now. thanks.

Comment: @bwoebi, ok, actually, that diverted a little from the original question... why then T::x() does not result in the E_STRICT warning that the manual talks about?

Comment: @gcb because of your error_reporting settings. Set `error_reporting(-1);` then you'll see it (but depends also on the PHP version you're having).

Comment: @bwoebi right. php cli was not using the php.ini i thought it was. you were right again. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X::x()` is actually a PHP4 style constructor, as it share the same name of the class. And calling constructors of a class in a static way raises a fatal error:

> Non-static method X::x() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

This actually is the case for all non-static magic methods as you can see in the implementation: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/Zend/zend_compile.c#1636

The only case where it might be implicitely called statically (and raise an `E_STRICT`) is when the function has no special handling:

```
if (some large if/else's for the magic methods) {
    // flag isn't set…
} else {
    CG(active_op_array)->fn_flags |= ZEND_ACC_ALLOW_STATIC;
}
```

Comment: @gcb because T::x() isn't a PHP4 style constructor (and this way not a magic method what allows static calls from incompatible context)? _For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for **the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class**._ from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: i still can't see how T::x() is any different than X::x(). If i remove the first test, which creates `new T()` from the code, the same thing happens. T::x() does not throw error. but X::() does.

Comment: @gcb `X::x()` is a constructor because the method name (x) is equal to the class name (X) (when ignoring case). `T::x()` is not a constructor because the method name (x) isn't equal to the class name (T). And as said in my answer: static calls on constructors fatal.

Comment: ah! of course! sorry, for some reason wasn't seeing that even with the previous explanations!

Comment: keep in mind that apparently is not case sensitive when calling classes, so x and X are the same